# How to get a user fields value in a Twig template (Drupal 8)?

Tags: twig, user-input, drupal-8

I am trying to get user field values in a Twig template. I created a text/list field in configuration->accountsettings->manage fields. The user can choose a currency e.g. USD/EUR/GBP

Afterwards, I want to get the chosen value in a Twig theme.

When I want to get the field value of a content type, I usually use:

```
{{ content.field_field_name.0 }}
```

How can I achieve the same for fields that are associated with users and not content? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this? Am wondering myself..

Comment: This answer here seems to be a good one: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template